# Text file output from Biztalk?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I have a mapping in Biztalk from an external XML schema to an internal XML schema. The internal schema I wish to map to a flat file schema. But that doesent seems to be possible. I cant select the flat file schema as destination schema. So I guess I need to use a flat file assembler in a send pipeline? But on properties on the flat file assembler the flat file schema is not visible under Document Schema.
Do you know how to do this?

I use Biztalk 2009

Comment: You need to create a flat file schema first.

Comment: I've also had issues with visual studio. Closing it and reopening will sometimes fix that

Answer (score 3):

+1 to what Jay said.

Moreover, You should do the following after step 2:

2.1 Create a new Map that references source schema (external schema) and destination schema (flat file schema created in step 2)

and then you should use this map to transform XML to flat file. This should be done using a send port configured with two things:

- pipeline (already mentioned in Jay's response, #3)
- Outbound Maps, you can find that in BizTalk Administration console under Send Port properties .. You should configure add the map you created in step 2.1 to the outbound maps.

Typically, you should be receiving the XML file on a receive location. so what you need to do is to create a new  receive port, and a receive location. and in the send port properties (again!) add a new filter with the following configuration:
BTS.ReceivePortName == XXXXX
Where XXXXX is the receive port name.

This way, any message is received on receipt port XXXXX is going to be sent to the send port with the map and pipeline already configured.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an example flat file that has the formatting you want for your output
2. Create a flat file schema using the flat file schema wizard. Use your example file as the input to the wizard.
3. create a pipeline. Put the flat file assembler into the pipeline.
4. Click on the flat file assembler shape and set the document schema to the flat file schema you created. This tells it the format of the output file.
5. Create a send port and use the pipeline you created.
6. Send your data to the send port.

Comment: May be worth adding that typically you would also need to create a map to the newly created flat file schema.